# Border around a single HtmlRow

Tags: c#, asp.net, row, border, visual-web-developer

I am trying to add a border to just one HtmlRow in C#. The row is going in a table that has a border around it's edge. I have tried:

```
row.Attributes.Add("border-bottom", "1px");
row.Attributes.Add("border-color", "#000000");
row.Attributes.Add("border-style", "solid");
row.Style.Add("border-width", "1px");
row.Style.Add("border-color", "#000000");
row.Style.Add("border-style", "solid");
row.BorderColor = "#000000";
```

resulting html for the row:

```
<tr class="tableHeader" Style="height:30px;border-width:1px;border-color:#000000;border-style:solid;" border-bottom="1px" border-color="#000000" border-style="solid" bordercolor="#000000">

<tr class="tableHeader" Style="height:30px;border-width:1px;border-color:#000000;border-style:solid;" border-bottom="1px" border-color="#000000" border-style="solid" bordercolor="#000000">
    <td width="25px" align="center"><FONT COLOR=#000000>Last</FONT></td>
    <td width="50px" align="center"><FONT COLOR=#000000>First</FONT></td>
    <td align="center" width="100px"><FONT COLOR=#000000>Address</FONT></td>
    <td width="50px" align="center"><FONT COLOR=#000000>Phone</FONT></td>
</tr>
```

But none of these have worked. I cannot use a table to make the border because the row is being used to model subsequent rows. Also, if this makes it easier, I only need the bottom of the row to have a border.

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with things like "C# and ASP.NET -". That's what we use tags for on [so].

Comment: Also, the purpose of that C# code is to affect the generated HTML. You should post the generated HTML.

Comment: Sorry, Still new to Stack Overflow

Comment: No problem. We learn by doing - and then by being told we could do better.

Comment: @John Saunders
I added the resulting html for the row. 

By the way, I was wondering why some of my questions have a negative number associated with them. Can you explain this? I know its off topic, but I dont know what to make of it.

Comment: I recommend you first create HTML by hand to get the appearance  you want, then get the .NET code to produce that HTML.

Comment: Please see the [faq]. Apparently, there are people who feel your questions aren't asked well.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should probably looking to put the style in a style sheet and use a class. it will also make it easier for you to test as you just need to add the style at run time and not each element that create the desired effect.

how about this http://jsfiddle.net/yQbTp/1/

```
<table id="border">
    <tr>
        <td>apple</td>
        <td>banana</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="border">
        <td>cherry</td>
        <td>date</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>egg</td>
        <td>fruit</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>grape</td>
        <td>ham</td>
    </tr>
</table>
table#border{
    width:100%;
    border:1px solid black;
}
table#border tr.border{
    border:1px solid red;
}
table#border tr:last-child{
    border:1px solid green;
}
```

Comment: This is very close to what I am looking for but not quite there. I tried this but I need to apply this to tables that are inserted from my C# class, which it does not seem to work on. Any suggestions on how to make that work?